# how to retrieve values from nsdictionary in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i am using a function to fill dictionary in a array
here is the code

```
    -(void)getAllFlashCardsNames
 {
if ([listofitems count]==0)
    listofitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
else
    [listofitems removeAllObjects];

for(int i=0;i<listOfCategoryId.count;i++)
{   
    int j=[[listOfCategoryId objectAtIndex:i]intValue];
    [self getFlashCard:j];      
    NSArray *flashCardsNames = flashCardsNamesList;
    NSArray *flashCardsids = flashCardsId;
    NSLog(@"FLash Card Ids %@",flashCardsids);      
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:flashCardsNames,@"flashCards",flashCardsids,@"flashCardId",nil];
    [listofitems addObject:dictionary];

}
```

}

in the above code the array flashcardsNamesList,flashCardsId changes everytime when calling the function [self getFlashCard:j]; j is a parameter to change categoryid which comes from the listOfCategoryId array..

now how do i retrieve values from the dictionary i want to show different flashcardsNames on different sections in uitableview.

here is the code i m using to retrieve values

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView { 
return [listofitems count];
```

}

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section   {   
    NSDictionary *dictionary =[listofitems objectAtIndex:section];
    NSLog(@"dictionary=%@",dictionary);
    NSArray *array =[dictionary objectForKey:@"flashCards"];
    NSLog(@"array=%@",array);
    NSLog(@"Section Count = %d",array.count);
    return array.count; 
}   



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {   
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";  
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell   *)[tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]; 
    if (cell == nil) {      
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];      
    }   

    NSDictionary *dictionary =[listofitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray *array =[dictionary objectForKey:@"flashCards"];
    NSArray *array1=[dictionary objectForKey:@"flashCardId"];
    NSString *cellValue=[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *cellValue1=[array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.FlashCardsNames setText:cellValue];
    [cell setFlashCardId:[cellValue1 intValue]];
    return cell;
}
```

but the method
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` does not get called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but the method `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` does not called

Have you set the object that your method is implemented in as the data source of your table view? `UITableView` hands some of the work off to another object, which must conform to the `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` protocols; you must then set the object as the `dataSource` and `delegate` of the table view, either in IB or programmatically (the data source and delegate can be different objects, but are commonly the same object). Take a look at [this article](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAPIOverview/TableViewAPIOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH4-SW1) which explains more about it; once this has been done, your object must handle the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` methods, which will be called on your object by the table view.

Also, the lines:

```
if ([listofitems count]==0)
    listofitems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

do not make sense. I assume you are checking whether the array has been allocated or not, and if not, to allocate it. If the array *hasn't* been allocated, it will be `nil`, so sending `count` to it will have no effect anyway. If it has been allocated previously, but deallocated but *not* reverted back to `nil` it will be a bad pointer and cause your application to crash.

A better way to allocate it would be to do so in your class's `awakeFromNib` method, or `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method, if you are implementing this in your `UIApplicationDelegate` subclass. Don't forget to release it in your `dealloc` method.

Comment: Have you set the object that your method is implemented in as the data source of your table view?

what does this means???

Comment: the method tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method is called but this line return 0 objects in the array
NSArray *array =[dictionary objectForKey:@"flashCards"]; 

i am stuck here..

Comment: When is getAllFlashCardsNames called, and in the line NSArray *flashCardsNames = flashCardsNamesList; where does `flashCsrdsNamesList` get populated with objects?

Comment: flashCardsNamesList; this is generated from database
and this method getAllFlashCardsNames is i am calling by passing categoryid to get flashCardsNamesList.and category id is generated from database